# VB.NET Using script with stringbuilder does not work

Tags: javascript, html, .net, vb.net, visual-studio

Here is an HTML file I have found on internet :

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<script>
var preEl ;
var orgBColor;
var orgTColor;
function HighLightTR(el, backColor,textColor){
  if(typeof(preEl)!='undefined') {
     preEl.bgColor=orgBColor;
     try{ChangeTextColor(preEl,orgTColor);}catch(e){;}
  }
  orgBColor = el.bgColor;
  orgTColor = el.style.color;
  el.bgColor=backColor;

  try{ChangeTextColor(el,textColor);}catch(e){;}
  preEl = el;
}
function ChangeTextColor(a_obj,a_color){  ;
   for (i=0;i<a_obj.cells.length;i++)
    a_obj.cells(i).style.color=a_color;
}
</script>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<br><br><br>
<table border=1 align=center>
<caption>Statistics</caption>
<th>Year</th>
<th>Team</th>
<tr  onClick="HighLightTR(this,'#c9cc99','cc3333');">
<td align=right>1930</td>
<td align=right>Detroit</td>
</tr>
<tr  onClick="HighLightTR(this,'#c9cc99','cc3333');">
<td align=right>1933</td>
<td align=right>Detroit</td>
</tr>
<tr  onClick="HighLightTR(this,'#c9cc99','cc3333');">
<td align=right>1934</td>
<td align=right>Detroit</td>
</tr>
<tr  onClick="HighLightTR(this,'#c9cc99','cc3333');">
<td align=right>1935</td>
<td align=right>Detroit</td>
</tr>
</table>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

If I load it in a webbrowser with :

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate("C:\Users\Mike\VB\HTMLScript\bin\Debug\testfile.html")
```

the script is correctly executed and works fine.

But doing like this :

```
    Dim sb As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()
    sb.Append("<HTML>")
    sb.Append("<HEAD>")
    sb.Append("<script>")
    sb.Append("var preEl ;")
    sb.Append("var orgBColor;")
    sb.Append("var orgTColor;")
    sb.Append("function HighLightTR(el, backColor,textColor){")
    sb.Append("  if(typeof(preEl)!='undefined') {")
    sb.Append("     preEl.bgColor=orgBColor;")
    sb.Append("     try{ChangeTextColor(preEl,orgTColor);}catch(e){;}")
    sb.Append("  }")
    sb.Append("  orgBColor = el.bgColor;")
    sb.Append("  orgTColor = el.style.color;")
    sb.Append("  el.bgColor=backColor;")
    sb.Append("")
    sb.Append("  try{ChangeTextColor(el,textColor);}catch(e){;}")
    sb.Append("  preEl = el;")
    sb.Append("}")
    sb.Append("function ChangeTextColor(a_obj,a_color){  ;")
    sb.Append("   for (i=0;i<a_obj.cells.length;i++)")
    sb.Append("    a_obj.cells(i).style.color=a_color;")
    sb.Append("}")
    sb.Append("</script>")
    sb.Append("</HEAD>")
    sb.Append("<BODY>")
    sb.Append("<br><br><br>")
    sb.Append("<table border=1 align=center>")
    sb.Append("<caption>Statistics</caption>")
    sb.Append("<th>Year</th>")
    sb.Append("<th>Team</th>")
    sb.Append("<tr  onClick=""HighLightTR(this,'#c9cc99','cc3333');"">")
    sb.Append("<td align=right>1930</td>")
    sb.Append("<td align=right>Detroit</td>")
    sb.Append("</tr>")
    sb.Append("<tr  onClick=""HighLightTR(this,'#c9cc99','cc3333');"">")
    sb.Append("<td align=right>1933</td>")
    sb.Append("<td align=right>Detroit</td>")
    sb.Append("</tr>")
    sb.Append("<tr  onClick=""HighLightTR(this,'#c9cc99','cc3333');"">")
    sb.Append("<td align=right>1934</td>")
    sb.Append("<td align=right>Detroit</td>")
    sb.Append("</tr>")
    sb.Append("<tr  onClick=""HighLightTR(this,'#c9cc99','cc3333');"">")
    sb.Append("<td align=right>1935</td>")
    sb.Append("<td align=right>Detroit</td>")
    sb.Append("</tr>")
    sb.Append("</table>")
    sb.Append("</BODY>")
    sb.Append("</HTML>")


    WebBrowser1.DocumentText = sb.ToString()
```

generates a script error. It tells me that a `;` is needed after the word `function` in the line below :

```
sb.Append("function HighLightTR(el, backColor,textColor){")
```

Or sometimes that `HighLightTR property value is null or undefined, not a function object`

I know that WebView2 is recommended but I really need to solve this problem in this old project. Please help me to solve this !
Thanks.

Comment: You're suing `Append` rather than `AppendLine`. That wouldn't matter for the HTML but it might well matter for the script part. Also, why do you have that rogue semicolon at the start of the second function?

Comment: It's pretty pointless to use a `StringBuilder` in that scenario anyway. Just use a multiline `String` literal, which have been supported for quite some time now, or an XML literal, which has been supported for even longer.

Comment: @jmcilhinney the semicolon was in the original code and I did not try to remove it. I have replaced sb.Append with sb.AppendLine and it works ! Thank you ! But it works only with WebBrowser1.DocumentText = sb.ToString() not with WebBrowser1.Document.Body.InnerHtml = sb.ToString. Any idea ?

Comment: What you have shown there is in entire HTML document, including head and body tags. If you set `Document.Body.InnerHtml` you're putting that value inside a body tag. You can't have a head tag and a body tag inside another body tag.

Comment: OK I will use WebBrowser1.DocumentText. Thanks to you I know better undersatnd this. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to jmcilhinney, replacing sb.Append with sb.AppendLine solved the problem !

The correct code is :

```
Dim sb As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()
sb.AppendLine("<HTML>")
sb.AppendLine("<HEAD>")
sb.AppendLine("<script>")
sb.AppendLine("var preEl ;")
sb.AppendLine("var orgBColor;")
Etc...
```